# Does the word “gather” make sense in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I’d like to know if it’s idiomatically correct to say the following:

> The clouds gather into a storm.

Does the word “gather” make sense in this context?

Comment: Is it an idiom? No. Does it make sense to most English readers? Yes. Can you use it? Yes.

Comment: The unusual element is the **into a storm**.  While storm clouds are often said to gather, (storm) clouds are not said to gather **into anything.**

Answer (score 2):

It is common in English to read descriptions of storm clouds "gathering." In fact, 'Storm Clouds Gathering' is the title of more than one book currently for sale on Amazon.com.

Here is a quote from the 14th Chairman of the U.S. Federal Reserve, using "clouds...gathering" within a war metaphor:

"The Depression was an incredibly dramatic episode - an era of stock-market crashes, breadlines, bank runs and wild currency speculation, with **the storm clouds of war gathering ominously** in the background ... For my money, few periods are so replete with human interest." -- Ben Bernanke